# How many cache lines are cached?

Tags: c++, caching, memory

Ok so I can't find much in the way of answers to this, it's a simple question in memory management.  I know that when a computer pulls from memory it caches 32-64 bits of memory in a cache line depending on your processor.  My question is does it only store 1 cache line's worth of memory or multiple, if multiple how many?

For instance say we're using c++, and I pull a `vector<int>` using a for loop, then I use those integers to pull information out of another `vector` that is most likely no where near it in memory.  Would that qualify as 2 pulls and then everything is cached or is that just going to continuously pull from memory?  Basically, would it pull the `vector<int>` and store it in cache, then pull the other `vector` and store it as well in a different catch line?  Thus only pulling twice then getting from it's cached memory from then on?  Assume that each vector = the size of 1 catch lines worth of data.

EDIT: Ok so on the same line....  I have a second question: Lets assume for a moment that my initial `vector<int>` is called and iterated over in a for loop, which then references multiple `vectors`.  When it caches those vectors, obviously it's going to have a limit so it will start writing over previous cache right?  In which case in what order would it write over the previous cache lines, FIFO, FILO, some other way?

Comment: Usually once they are in the cache, they will stay there for a long time, considering your data is small(only one cache line each and only two of them).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was curious of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different types of cache. Generally, the amount of cache depends on the processor. A moden processor has 3 levels of cache, where the fastest (and smallest) is called L1 and usually range between 128kb and 512kb, where the slowest (and largest) is 1mb to 4mb.

Each access to the memory is 64 bit long, regardless of the processor architecture. Therefore accessing the memory with 64bit long operands is most efficient.

The cache may store memory from different pages too.

Comment: So essentially what your saying is yes it would most likely cache multiple cache lines?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify if/how this answer the question?